# Will adding my site to Google Search Console in a new Google account affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I need to make another Google account.

Can I sign in to Google Webmaster Tools to re-add my sites for SEO? I had added this site with my old Gmail account.

Will changing the associated Google account affect my SEO?

Comment: Why do you need to make another Google account?? What happened? Understanding this may help us help you.

Comment: BTW- Having a Google account does not effect SEO, however, it is good to have anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your SEO has nothing to do with the Google account you have set up for your GWT login. It is quite common that a different person with different login details will come in and try to set up GWT for the domain. To deal with this Google will have you re-authenticate the site with a new verification meta tag to prove that you have authority on the site. Once this is done you should have no issues. As for the question about how this will affect SEO as per above and the comment from @closetnoc there will be no change to your SEO (SERP ranking) due to the change as the ranking is based on the site itself and not the associated Google account.